# Dynamically stating FROM which table name to SELECT from

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, dynamic-sql

Would it be possible to use a system query to retrieve TABLE name and then `SELECT * FROM that TABLE name`. Along the lines of:

```
SELECT * FROM CAST (( SELECT TOP 1 t.Name 
                      FROM sys.tables t 
                      JOIN sys.columns c ON c.OBJECT_ID = t.OBJECT_ID 
                      WHERE c.NAME = 'SomeColumnID' )  AS sys.tables )
```

The current issue is that the `SELECT TOP 1 t.Name` will return a string and could it be then cast into a valid `Tables.Name`.

Comment: So you want to specify the Column Name and then select all records from all tables having that Column Name?

Comment: You are looking for dynamic SQL, here is an [introduction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and there are many tutorials on the web, including examples similar to what you are trying to do.

Comment: @DaleK that could be one use case of this snippet of code,  I wrote it as a TOP 1, but ALL would be better. I am currently giving the link a read, thank You

Comment: @FarisKapo Tips: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space or reserved words like `From`. Do read up on [SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need dynamic sql for this: that is, build a query string from a query, then execute it with `sp_executesql`.

For your use case, that would look like:

```
declare @q nvarchar(max);

select top (1) @q = N'select * from ' + t.name 
from sys.tables t 
join sys.columns c on c.object_id = t.object_id 
where c.name = 'SomeColumnID'

-- debuug the query
select @q sql;

-- execute the query
execute sp_executesql @q;
```